# How to import latest database backup file to backup server

Tags: mysql, linux, ls, gunzip

I want to import the backup database file in *.sql.gz to my backup server.
I try to use the follow command but there is an error with it

```
ls -Art *.sql.gz | tail -n 1 | gunzip -c | mysql --user=user --password=password database
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
```

So how can I pipe the latest files to gunzip is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `xargs`:

```
ls -Art *.sql.gz |tail -n 1 |xargs gunzip -c | mysql --user=user --password=password database
```